# Second eigenvalue of primitive matrix

Tags: graph-theory, markov-chains, spectral-graph-theory, symbolic-dynamics

Let $A$ be a primitive $N\times N$-matrix with positive entries, that is there is $n>0$ such that $(A^n)_{i,j}>0$ for all $i,j$. For brevity, assume the entries consist only of $0$ and $1$.

The Perron-Frobenius theorem gives, among other things, a distinguished eigenvalue $\lambda_1>1$ that is simple and for all the other eigenvalues $\lambda_j$ it holds that $|\lambda_j|<\lambda_1$.

I would like to ask if there is a characterization of matrices $A$ (or associated strongly connected graphs) for which it holds that $|\lambda_j|\leq 1$, for every $j\neq 1$? Thanks!

Comment: @FedorPetrov, just edited it. Thanks

Comment: A related question I asked many years ago, which was answered, giving an algorithm for testing if an eigenvalue lies on the unit circle or not. With this, and a numerical method that can arbitrarily approximate eigenvalues, you can algorithmically determine if a matrix satisfies your condition (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1436637/how-to-test-if-a-primitive-matrix-has-an-eigenvalue-of-unit-modulus)

Comment: It should also be mentioned that the matrices of your type have characteristic polynomials that are either Pisot or Salem.

Comment: @DanRust, very helpful comments! thanks!